# Firebase: How to update arrays length when manually delete one path?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On my website a user can enter multiple addresses. The file structure looks like this:

[image]

I load the data to the users profile so that he can change it and add different cities if needed. To do that I loop through each address in a for-loop. For that purpose I need the correct length of address. But since address is an array after deleting one address the length still stays at two.

What options do I have?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Push method of Firebase instead of saving data in arrays

```
var ref=firebase.databae().ref("user/"+uid+"/address");
ref.push({city:"ABC",houseNo:"444",postalCode:"3433",street:"street"});
```

[Firebase Save Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/save-data)

Why to avoid arrays,please check [Best Practice for Arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn`t know that if using a number as a key it gets automatically transferred to an array in firebase. I created an object but it was transferred.

Comment: yes it will do that, so you should read documentation before experiment